# Objects in go getting replaced

Tags: go

I'm learning go by writing a web spider. I'm trying to get a list of all the business categories from `allpages.com`.

Below is my entire program. Unfortunately I can't isolate the issue so I've pasted it all.

If you run this program, you'll see that first of all it correctly downloads the first page, and adds all the extracted categories to the list of categories.

However, when it then downloads subsequent pages, it seems to mess up the reference to the parent category. E.g. it incorrectly calculates the URL `http://www.allpages.com/travel-tourism/political-ideological-organizations/`, when in fact `political-ideological-organizations/` is not a subcategory of `travel-tourism/`. Digging through the logs it seems to overwrite the data in the `parent` object. The error is more pronounced the more workers there are.

This was working a bit better before I started passing data by reference to the goroutine, but I had essentially the same issue.

I've got several questions:

1. How can I debug this without resorting to picking through log lines?
2. What's wrong/why isn't it working and how can it be fixed?

   ```
   package main

   import (
           "fmt"
           "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
           "log"
           "strconv"
           "strings"
           "regexp"
   )

   const domain = "http://www.allpages.com/"
   const categoryPage = "category.html"

   type Category struct {
           url string
           level uint
           name string
           entries int
           parent *Category
   }

   type DownloadResult struct {
           doc *goquery.Document
           category *Category
   }

   const WORKERS = 2
   const SEPARATOR = "§§§"

   func main() {

           allCategories := make([]Category, 0)

           downloadChannel := make(chan *Category)
           resultsChannel := make(chan *DownloadResult, 100)

           for w := 1; w <= WORKERS; w++ {
                   go worker(downloadChannel, resultsChannel)
           }

           numRequests := 1
           downloadChannel <- &Category{ domain + categoryPage, 0, "root", 0, nil }

           for result := range resultsChannel {
                   var extractor func(doc *goquery.Document) []string

                   if result.category.level == 0 {
                           extractor = topLevelExtractor
                   } else if result.category.level == 1 {
                           extractor = secondLevelExtractor
                   } else {
                           extractor = thirdLevelExtractor
                   }

                   categories := extractCategories(result.doc, result.category, extractor)
                   allCategories = append(allCategories, *categories...)

                   //fmt.Printf("Appending categories: %v", *categories)

                   fmt.Printf("total categories = %d, total requests = %d\n", len(allCategories), numRequests)

                   for _, category := range *categories {
                           numRequests += 1
                           downloadChannel <- &category
                   }

                   // close the channels when there are no more jobs
                   if len(allCategories) > numRequests {
                           close(downloadChannel)
                           close(resultsChannel)
                   }
           }

           fmt.Println("Done")
   }

   func worker(downloadChannel <-chan *Category, results chan<- *DownloadResult) {
           for target := range downloadChannel {
                   fmt.Printf("Downloading %v (addr %p) ...", target, &target)

                   doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(target.url)
                   if err != nil {
                           log.Fatal(err)
                           panic(err)
                   }

                   fmt.Print("done \n")

                   results <- &DownloadResult{doc, target}
           }
   }

   func extractCategories(doc *goquery.Document, parent *Category, extractor func(doc *goquery.Document) []string) *[]Category {

           numberRegex, _ := regexp.Compile("[0-9,]+")

           log.Printf("Extracting subcategories for page %s\n", parent)

           subCategories := extractor(doc)

           categories := make([]Category, 0)

           for _, subCategory := range subCategories {
                   log.Printf("Got subcategory=%s from parent=%s", subCategory, parent)
                   extracted := strings.Split(subCategory, SEPARATOR)

                   numberWithComma := numberRegex.FindString(extracted[2])
                   number := strings.Replace(numberWithComma, ",", "", -1)

                   numRecords, err := strconv.Atoi(number)
                   if err != nil {
                           log.Fatal(err)
                           panic(err)
                   }

                   var category Category

                   level := parent.level + 1

                   if parent.level == 0 {
                           category = Category{ domain + extracted[1], level, extracted[0], numRecords, parent }
                   } else {
                           log.Printf("category URL=%s, parent=%s, parent=%v", extracted[1], parent.url, parent)
                           category = Category{ parent.url + extracted[1], level, extracted[0], numRecords, parent }
                   }

                   log.Printf("Appending category=%v (pointer=%p)", category, &category)

                   categories = append(categories, category)
           }

           return &categories
   }

   func topLevelExtractor(doc *goquery.Document) []string {
           return doc.Find(".cat-listings-td .c-1s-2m-1-td1").Map(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) string {
                   title := s.Find("a").Text()
                   url := s.Find("a").Map(func(x int, a *goquery.Selection) string {
                           v, _ := a.Attr("href")
                           return v
                   })
                   records := s.Clone().Children().Remove().End().Text()

                   //log.Printf("Item %d: %s, %s - %s\n", i, title, records, url)

                   res := []string{title, url[0], records}
                   return strings.Join(res, SEPARATOR)
           })
   }

   func secondLevelExtractor(doc *goquery.Document) []string {
           return doc.Find(".c-2m-3c-1-table .c-2m-3c-1-td1").Map(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) string {
                   title := s.Find("a").Text()
                   url := s.Find("a").Map(func(x int, a *goquery.Selection) string {
                           v, _ := a.Attr("href")
                           return v
                   })
                   records := s.Clone().Children().Remove().End().Text()

                   //log.Printf("Item %d: %s, %s - %s\n", i, title, records, url)

                   res := []string{title, url[0], records}
                   return strings.Join(res, SEPARATOR)
           })
   }

   func thirdLevelExtractor(doc *goquery.Document) []string {
           return doc.Find(".c-2m-3c-1-table .c-2m-3c-1-td1").Map(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) string {
                   title := s.Find("a").Text()
                   url := s.Find("a").Map(func(x int, a *goquery.Selection) string {
                           v, _ := a.Attr("href")
                           return v
                   })
                   records := s.Clone().Children().Remove().End().Text()

                   //log.Printf("Item %d: %s, %s - %s\n", i, title, records, url)

                   res := []string{title, url[0], records}
                   return strings.Join(res, SEPARATOR)
           })
   }
   ```

**Update**
Fixed - see comment below.

Comment: Could you provide a much *smaller* and standalone snippet which demonstrates the problem? Most probably the problem is hidden in a lot of noise.

Comment: @Volker unfortunately as I explained I have no idea what's going on so I can't condense it.

Comment: Do you think this is a good question for SO? Will an answer be helpful for others too?

Comment: @Volker Definitely. The issue was using looping over `for _, category := range *categories` and passing a reference to `&category`. This was passing a reference to the variable used in the generator, rather than the underlying element. Changing it to loop over `for i := 0; i < len(*categories); i++` has fixed the issue.

Comment: Note that the underlying problem was using "pointer to slice" which is wrong in most cases and definitively in your case: Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over:

```
            for _, category := range *categories {
                    numRequests += 1
                    downloadChannel <- &category
            }
```

meant I was sending a reference to the temporary variable `category` to the channel, instead of the actual memory address of that value.

I've fixed this by using a different loop:

```
    for i := 0; i < len(*categories); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Queuing category: %v (%p)", categoriesValues[i], categoriesValues[i])

        downloadChannel <- &categoriesValues[i]
    }
```